# Concatenate two string variables in Python's Tornado framework

Tags: python, templates, web, tornado, jinja2

I've been reviewing the Tornado API and I can't figure out how to concatenate two strings, where one is typed, and one is a variable. Tornado does not seem to inherit from Jinja2/Django templates.

The end goal is to use a dynamically generated variable as a GET request attribute. I could use a form with a hidden variable, but there are hundreds of generated values to be rendered at the same time.

I've included one example as a proof of work, but I've also tried examples using Django/Jinja2 templates. Any suggestions?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-6 columns">
        <table>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Broken</th>
            <th>Placed</th>
            <th>Kills</th>
            <th>Deaths</th>
            {% for player in players %}
                <tr>
                    <td><a href='/players/' + {{ player.player }}>{{player.player}}</a></td>
                    <td><a href="#">{{player.blocks_broken}}</a></td>
                    <td><a href="#">{{player.blocks_placed}}</a></td>
                    <td><a href="#">{{player.kills}}</a></td>
                    <td><a href="#">{{player.deaths}}</a></td>
               </tr>
           {% end %}
       </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

This results in the following URL: `localhost:8888/players`

The desired output is: `localhost:8888/players/bob`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just have that line read as:

```
<td><a href='/players/{{ player.player }}'>{{player.player}}</a></td>
```

No concatenation required, it'll be constructed before it hits the browser.

Comment: You can also do this by putting the concatenation inside the expression: `href="{{ '/players/' + player.player }}"`

Comment: I honestly can't believe that I didn't think to try this. Thanks! Ben, I've noticed that you're the development lead for Tornado. Is there an official forum for Tornado related questions?